# html5 canvas clock

Tags: html, canvas

I'm looking into this clock. I have no experience with the js that comes with this file.

Here is the [demo](http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/242/index.html)

Here is all the [code](http://css.dzone.com/articles/html5-canvas-clock-keeps)

How can I edit the face of the clock?

I'm looking at this and I would like more control over what the hands look like. Can someone tell me what makes them come to a point. How could I make them just a thick line?

```
 // draw hour
ctx.save();
var theta = (hour - 3) * 2 * Math.PI / 12;
ctx.rotate(theta);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-15, -5);
ctx.lineTo(-15, 5);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.5, 1);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.5, -1);
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();

// draw minute
ctx.save();
var theta = (minute - 15) * 2 * Math.PI / 60;
ctx.rotate(theta);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-15, -4);
ctx.lineTo(-15, 4);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, 1);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, -1);
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();

// draw second
ctx.save();
var theta = (seconds - 15) * 2 * Math.PI / 60;
ctx.rotate(theta);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-15, -3);
ctx.lineTo(-15, 3);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.9, 1);
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.9, -1);
ctx.fillStyle = '#0f0';
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();

ctx.restore();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try playing around with the different parameters on the `.lineTo` rows and see what happens, maybe you can draw conclusions from that :) Or read up on the `.lineTo` method used, it is what actually draws the shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what each of the calls to `ctx` do to make the hand:

```
ctx.rotate(theta);   // Rotates the canvas according to the hand position.
ctx.beginPath();     // Start drawing a path.
ctx.moveTo(-15, -4); // Set the "brush"/"pen" at center left corner.
ctx.lineTo(-15, 4);  // Draw a line to position center right corner.
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, 1);  // Draw a line to the edge, right corner.
ctx.lineTo(clockRadius * 0.8, -1); // Draw a line to the edge, left corner.
ctx.fill();          // Fill the polygon we just drew.
ctx.restore();       // Rotate the canvas back.
```

So, for example, changing the `1` and `-1` values to `4` and `-4` would make a thick rectangular face.

More learnin' can be aquired here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

Comment: Also, set the stroke thickness:  ctx.lineWidth = 5;